# Display Different Lookup Field Each Time An Item Is Selected in Picklist Field

Tags: visualforce

I have an object named `Expenses__c`. This object has a field named `Expense_Type__c`, which contains these values: **Customer** and **Employee**.

Here's the requirement: When I select **Customer** from `Expense_Type__c` picklist field, a lookup field (named `Customer__c`) for `Customer` object must be displayed. But when I select `Employee`, lookup field (named `Employee__c`) for `Employee` object must appear. These lookup fields must only be displayed upon the selection of their controlling picklist value.

I've already used `actionSupport`, and actually it's working. The only problem is that it works only in `Customer`, not in `Employee`. How can I solve this?

By the way, here's my code:

**Vf page** : **ExpensePage**

```
<apex:page standardController="Expenses__c">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageblock>
      <apex:selectList value="{!Expenses__c.Type__c}" size="1">  
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="lookup1"/> 
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="lookup2"/>              
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="--None--" itemLabel="--None--"/> 
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Customer" itemLabel="Customer"/> 
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Employee" itemLabel="Employee"/> 
      </apex:selectList> 

      <apex:outputPanel id="lookup1">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Expenses__c.Customer__c}" rendered="{!Expenses__c.Type__c='Customer'}"/>
      </apex:outputPanel>

      <apex:outputPanel id="lookup2">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Expenses__c.Employee__c}" rendered="{!Expenses__c.Type__c='Employee'}"/>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Consolidate your two `actionSupport` tags into one, you can use a comma separated list.

Comment: Very simple than I've imagined! It's working, thanks @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consolidate your two `actionSupport` tags into one, you can use a comma separated list.

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="lookup1,lookup1" />
```